# Prime Factorization of $15^8 + 16$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have created a problem and I am not able to find the answer. What is the prime factorization of $15^8 + 16$? The thing is I can find an answer with a calculator easily, but what is the step by step approach to the problem.

Comment: Note that $15^8+16=15^8+15+1$ and $x^2+x+1$ is a factor of the polynomial $x^8+x+1$...

Comment: Any reason to imagine it has an especially nice factoring?  In general, it isn't easy to factor numbers.  In this case, it seems easy to notice that $17$ is a factor (as $2^8\equiv 1\pmod {17}$).  But you are still left with a fairly large number to factor.

Comment: 2562890641 = 17×97×241×6449 (4 distinct prime factors)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Put $\ x\!=\!15,\ I,J,K = 8,1,0\ $ below (proved in a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/242) on $\,14^7\!+14^2\!+1)$

$$  \ x^{\large 2}\!+\!x\!+\!1 \,\mid\, x^I\! + x^J\! + x^K\quad {\rm if}\quad\{I,J,K\}\equiv \{2,1,0\}\!\!\!\pmod 3\,$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
  n^8+n+1 &= (n^2+n+1)(n^6-n^5+n^3-n^2+1) \\
  15^8+15+1 &= (15^2+15+1)(15^6-15^5+15^3-15^2+1) \\
  &= 241 \times 10634401  \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Maybe the downvote is because this factor has already been mentioned a half hour ago in a comment (and another way in an answer) so why duplicate that without adding anything new?

Comment: @BillDubuque Not a good reason to downvote, IMO. (+1)

Comment: I've rebooted my PC $N$ times.

Answer (score 0):

To be less clever than the other answers: The Pollard rho method works well here.  I ran it with $f(x) =x^2+1$ and seed value $x_0=2$ and got the factor $97$ at the third step (I had to compute $x_6$.   With $f(x) = x^2+2$, it gave the factor $4097$ at the fourth step.