# Obtaining some elements of Galois field $2^q$

Tags: finite-fields, maple

Consider an $n$-tuple $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_n)$ where $\alpha_i$, $1\leq i \leq n$, are elements of the
Galois field $GF(2^q)$. We know that the [elementary symmetric  polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_j$,  $1\leq j \leq k$, 
over the $n$-tuple $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_n)$ are defined  as follows

\begin{eqnarray}
e_1(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_n)&=&\sum_{1\leq j \leq n} \, \alpha_j\quad ,\\
\\
e_2(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_n)&=&\sum_{1\leq j<k \leq n} \, \alpha_j\, \alpha_k \quad ,\\
\\
e_k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_n)&=&\sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2<\cdots <j_k \leq n} \, \alpha_{j_1}\cdots \alpha_{j_k} \quad .
\end{eqnarray}

In my research, I need an example of eight-tuple $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_8)$ where $\alpha_i$, $1\leq i \leq 8$, be 
elements of the Galois field $GF(2^8)$ such that
$$
e_i(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_8)=0 \quad , \quad 1\leq i \leq 4 \quad . 
$$

I want to ask you to help me to obtain this example. If you find this example, please clarify with which primitive 
polynomial you have constructed the Galious field $GF(2^8)$.

I wrote a [Maple code](https://transfer.sh/hZi8w/1.mw) for obtaining this example, but because of there are $256 \choose 8$ cases for choosing $\alpha_i$'s and
  limitation of my computer CPU and RAM, I could not find an example. The
JPG format of my Maple code is [in the following form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBtAM.jpg).

I would greatly appreciate for any assistance.

**Edit:**

Based on the efficient and excellent answers of *Professor Robert Israel* and *Jyrki Lahtonen*, I want to add an addition condition as follows

$$
e_i(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_8)=0 \quad , \quad 1\leq i \leq 4 \quad, \quad e_j(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_8)\neq0 \quad , \quad 5\leq j \leq 7\, .$$

Comment: I suppose you don't want the obvious example: all $\alpha_j = 0$, or the slightly less obvious: all $\alpha_j$ equal.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes you right. I need $\alpha_j$'s be distinct. Thanks Professor Israel for comment and wait for your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @RobertIsrael In Maple I used $choose([0..27],8)$ but I did not find answer. For interval bigger than $[0..27]$ Maple made error that "object is too big".

Comment: @RobertIsrael In fact, I have no reason  that are there $\alpha_j$'s in $GF(2^8)$ or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $GF(2^8)$ generated by a root $\beta$ of the polynomial $x^8+x^6+x^5+x^2+1$ over $GF(2)$, take
$$\eqalign{0,\; {\beta}^{3}+\beta,\;{\beta}^{7}+{\beta}^{5}+{\beta}^{2},\;{\beta}^{6}+{
\beta}^{5}+\beta+1,\;{\beta}^{6}+{\beta}^{5}+{\beta}^{3}+1,\;\cr{\beta}^{7}+{
\beta}^{5}+{\beta}^{3}+{\beta}^{2}+\beta,\;{\beta}^{7}+{\beta}^{6}+{
\beta}^{2}+\beta+1,\;{\beta}^{7}+{\beta}^{6}+{\beta}^{3}+{\beta}^{2}+1
}$$

Maple code:

```
P:= x^8+x^6+x^5+x^2+1:
alias(beta = RootOf(P)):
randc:= proc() add(rand(0..1)()*beta^j,j=0..7) end proc:
for iter from 1 do
  Q:= x^8 + add(randc()*x^j,j=1..3);
  F:= (Factors(Q,beta) mod 2)[2];
  if nops(F) = 8 then
     print(map(t -> subs(x=0,t[1]), F));
     break
  fi
od:
```

Comment: Really Really Really thanks for your answer. Mr Professor Israel you are man of MAPLE. Thanks a Million.

Comment: I wish, I had 1000 reputation to present for your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: What a nice and efficient Maple code you have written.

Comment: Dear Professor B.Israel, I want to ask you to help me in the following question. How to modify your maple code such that find an eight tuple $x=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_8)$, in the following form $$e_1(x) =e_2(x)=\cdots=e_7(x)=0$$. If thers is no such $x$ in $GF(2^8)$, is it possible to tell how to change your Maple code for $GF(2^{16})$ in order to generate the mentioned eight tuple $x$ where $$ e_i(x)=0\, , \, 1\leq i \leq 7$$ I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.

Comment: An $8$-tuple so that $e_1(x) = \ldots = e_7(x) = 0$ means  $\prod_{i=1}^8 (X - \alpha_i) = X^8 + c$.  But this being characteristic $2$, every member of your field is an $8$'th power, so $X^8 + c$ always splits as $(X+d)^8$ for some $d$.  Thus the only solutions over $GF(2^m)$ have all $\alpha_i$ equal.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong Robert Israel's answer. I simply cannot resist describing a bit of theory leading to some (but not all) solutions.

---

TL;DR; version: If $\beta$ is a primitive element of $GF(256)$, then
$$
x^8+\beta^{85}x^2+x
$$
has eight distinct zeros in $GF(256)$, and for them we have $e_1=e_2=e_3=e_4=e_5=0.$ On with the longer version...

---

Assume that $V\subset GF(2^q)$ is a 3-dimensional subspace (over $GF(2)$). Consider the octic polynomial that has zeros at the points of $V$:
$$
L_V(x)=\prod_{z\in V}(x-z).
$$
I will show that $L_v$ has only terms of degrees $1,2,4$ and $8$.

Let $v\in GF(2^q)$. The polynomial
$$p_v(x)=x^2-vx$$
obviously vanishes at $0$ and $v$. Furthermore, $p_v(x)$ is a so called
*linearized polynomial*, meaning that
$$
p_v(x+y)=p_v(x)+p_v(y).
$$
Let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be a basis of $V$. Because $p_{v_1}(x)$ is linearized, we see that 
$$p_{v_1}(v_2)=p_{v_1}(v_2)+p_{v_1}(v_1)=p_{v_1}(v_1+v_2).$$
Therefore the composition
$$
p_{v_1,v_2}(x):=p_{p_{v_1}(v_2)}(p_{v_1}(x))
$$
vanishes at the points $0,v_1,v_2,v_1+v_2$. Furthermore, by the composition rule (and Freshman's dream in characteristic two) we see that 
$p_{v_1,v_2}(x)$ only has terms of degrees $1,2$ and $4$, and hence it, too,
is a linearized polynomial.

Repeating the dose then shows that
$$
p_{v_1,v_2,v_3}(x):=p_{p_{v_1,v_2}(v_3)}(p_{v_1,v_2}(x))
$$
vanishes at the points of $V$, only has terms of degrees $1,2,4$ and $8$, and hence is also linearized. Because this octic is also monic, it must be equal to $L_V(x)$.

Anyway,
$$
L_V(x)=x^8+e_4(V)x^4+e_6(V)x^2+e_7(V)x,
$$
where the $e_i$:s are the elementary symmetric polynomials of the set $V$.
In particular, we automatically have $e_1(V)=e_2(V)=e_3(V)=0$ hopefully explaining why I wanted to explain this to you.

So selecting your elements $\alpha_i, i=1,2,\ldots,8,$ to be the elements of a subspace $V$ gives us $e_1=e_2=e_3=0$ automatically leaving us to deal with $e_4$. We are lead to look for subspaces $V$ such that
$$
L_V(x)=x^8+ Ax^2+Bx,
$$
when we will in addition to the above get $e_4=e_5=0$. To make the search simpler let us consider the effect of scaling. If we multiply the subspace $V$ by an element $\alpha\in GF(2^q)$, we get the subspace
$$
\alpha V=\{\alpha z\mid z\in V\}.
$$
Clearly $e_6(\alpha V)=\alpha^6 e_6(V)$ and $e_7(\alpha V)=\alpha^7e_7(V)$. As raising to seventh power is a bijection of $GF(2^8)$ we can, by selecting a suitable $\alpha$, without loss of generality assume that $e_7(V)=1$.
We are thus left with polynomials of the form
$$
L_a(x)=x^8+ax^2+x.
$$
We need to select $a$ in such a way that $L_a(x)$ has eight zeros in $GF(2^8)$. Because all the elements of $GF(256)$ are zeros of $P(x)=x^{256}-x$, we want to check that $L_a(x)$ is a factor of $P(x)$.
Using square-and-multiply (and Freshman's dream!!!) it is actually a pencil-and-paper calculation to find the remainder! It turns out that
$$
P(x)\equiv(1+a^{42})x^4+(a^5+a^{33}+a^{40})x^2+(1+a^4+a^{32})x\pmod{L_a(x)}.
$$
So $L_a(x)$ will give us what we want if all those three polynomials on $a$ vanish.
It follows from [Bill Dubuque's answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/11619) that if $a$ is a primitive third root of unity, i.e. it satisfies the equation $a^2+a+1$, then we, indeed, get
$$
L_a(x)\mid P(x).
$$

Observe that already the field $GF(4)\subset GF(256)$ contains the primitive third roots of unity. If $\beta$ is a primitive element of the field $GF(256)$, then $\beta^{85}$ can serve in the role of $a$ in $L_a(x)$.

Furthermore, by linearity of $L_a(x)$, the cosets of the subspace
$V:=\operatorname{Ker}(L_a)$ are zeros of polynomials of the form $L_a(x)+c$
for some $c\in GF(256)$. There are $32$ such cosets, so you get $8$ zeros in $GF(256)$ for $32$ different choices of $c$. Any of those $32$ cosets will
serve as your set $\alpha_i, i=1,2,\ldots,8$.

Comment: What I say in the last paragraphs also applies, of course, to the scaled versions $$x^8+\gamma^6\beta^{85}x^2+\gamma^7x$$ for any $\gamma\in GF(256)^*$.

Comment: It is a great and excellent proof, Professor Jyrki Lahtonen. I have a question that I ask in the next comment.

Comment: Glad to hear you are interested. It is past midnight here, so I need to call it a day.

Comment: Thanks again Professor Jyrki Lahtonen for complete post you made.

Comment: Every time I read your answer, I enjoy it.

Comment: One of the interesting $8$-tuple $x=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_8)$ is the time $e_1(x)=e_2(x)=\cdots=e_6(x)=0$. Withe the same arguments that you did for the pervious question we can show that the solution of the equation $P(X)=X^8+e_7\,X+e_8$ is in the following form: $\alpha_1=a$ and $\alpha_j=a+b\, \omega^{j-2}$ for $2\leq j \leq 8$, in which $a,b$ and $\omega$ are elements of finite field $GF(2^q)$ such that the order of  $\omega$ is $7$ and $7\mid 2^q-1$.  Dear Professor Jyrki Lahtonen thank you so much for every thing you have done to help me during these $2$ questions.

Comment: Well spotted @user0410! I did not bring that up, because that case only happens when $3\mid q$. And, please, don't call me a professor, I'm not :-) And, this site is quite egalitarian in many way. Admittedly there are a few users I am inclined to only address with a honorific tagged on - prof. Lubin springs to mind :-)

Comment: Apparently I am not one of the your students at the  university of Turku, but actually you are my professor of mathematics in math stack. Thanks Professor Jyrki Lahtonen :-)