# Factor $x^5+x^4+1$ into irreducible polynomials in $Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

The answer paper says we can do it like this $(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)$, but I dont know how they got that. Can you please write a step by step tutorial?:D Thank you! (Since $0$ and $1$ are not roots, I can’t even start to factorize)

Comment: The number of (irreducible) polynomials in $\Bbb F_2[x]$ of degree lower or equal to $n$ is finite, so this possibility is always at hand.

Comment: Note that the only way it can be factored is into degree 2 and 3, as it's quite easy to prove it has no rational roots. 4+1 or 3+1+1 or 2+2+1 for example all include linear roots

Comment: This factorization is essentially also true over the integers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286149/prove-that-n5n41-is-composite-for-n1/2287249?noredirect=1#comment4707391_2287249

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it can be factored, it is factored as the product of irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ and $3$ respectively since it has no roots. So we may try to see whether it is divisible by an irreducible quadratic polynomial, i.e. a quadratic polynomial with no root. Over $\mathbf Z_2$, the single quadratic irreducible polynomial is $x^2+x+1$, since the other quadratic polynomials are
$$x^2+x=x(x+1)\quad\text{ and }\quad x^2+1=(x+1)^2.$$
It happens the quotient  is $x^3+x+1$, and it is irreducible since it has no root either.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Let $f=x^5+x^4+1$. Then:

- $\gcd(f,x^2-x)$ is a possible factor of $f$ of degree at most $1$
- $\gcd(f,x^4-x)$ is a possible factor of $f$ of degree at most $2$
- $\gcd(f,x^8-x)$ is a possible factor of $f$ of degree at most $3$
- $\gcd(f,x^{32}-x)=f$ iff $f$ is irreducible mod $2$

All gcds can be easily found with the Euclidean algorithm.

*Solution:*

- $\gcd(f,x^2-x)=1$
- $\gcd(f,x^4-x)=x^2 + x + 1$
- $\gcd(f,x^8-x)=x^3 + x + 1$
- $f=(x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + x + 1)$

The two factors are irreducible mod $2$ because they have no roots.