# Satisfying the third root of unity implies $g(x) \mid f(x)$, why?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Consider the polynomial : $\mathcal{f(x)}=x^{10}+x^5+1$ and $\mathcal{g(x)}=x^2+x+1$. 
It's known that the third root of unity $\omega$ satisfies the equation, so, we can say $\mathcal{f(x)}=\mathcal{g(x)\cdot h(x)}$.

Please explain why/how the fact that the third root of unity satisfies the equation implies $\mathcal{g(x) \mid f(x)}$

Comment: $g$ is the so-called _minimal polynomial_ for $\omega$ over $\Bbb Q$ (or over $\Bbb R$, for that matter). It is a general result that if $\alpha$ is algebraic and $f(\alpha)=0$, then $f$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\bmod\, x^{\large 2}\!+\!x\!+\!1\!:\,\ x^{\large 3}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large \color{#c00}{10}}+x^{\large\color{#0a0}5}+1\equiv x^{\large \color{#c00}1}+x^{\large \color{#0a0}2}+1\equiv 0$

---

**Remark** $ $ Generally this shows $\ x^{2}\!+\!x\!+\!1\mid x^\color{#c00}A\! +\! x^\color{#0a0}B\! +\! x^C\ $ if $ \ \{\color{#c00}A,\color{#0a0}B,C\}\equiv \{\color{#0a0}2,\color{#c00}1,0\}\pmod{\!3}.$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/242) for further discussion and generalizations.

Note: above $x$ is an "indeterminate" not a specific root, i.e. we do polynomial arithmetic in $\,\Bbb Z[x].\,$ Comparing to Ennar's answer, instead of doing Euclidean division of $\,f\,$ by $\,x^2+x+1\,$ we do a division by its multiple $\,x^3−1\,$ which is *simpler*, since we need only the remainder, hence we need only compute $\,f\bmod\, x^3−1\,$ doable *simply* by applying the rewrite rule $\,x^3\to 1,\,$ i.e.
$$\ f\bmod x^2\!+\!x\!+\!1\ =\ \underbrace{(f\bmod x^3\!-1)}_{\Large x^3\to\, 1}\bmod x^2\!+\!x\!+\!1$$

a "mod" optimization we all know subconsciously since grade school, where we frequently use

$$n\bmod 2\ = \ (n\bmod 10)\bmod 2$$

to compute the parity (even/odd) of $\,n\,$ via the parity of its units digit $= n\bmod 10$

As I explain in the linked answer, the same modular optimization works for any factor of a "simple" polynomial (e.g. a binomial or fewnomial, or one that is easy to compute modulo it)

Comment: I don't think that the question was to prove that $\omega$ is root of $f$, but how it implies $g\mid f$.

Comment: @ennar But that is what we prove above.

Comment: Oh, ok, you are completely right.

Comment: I understand what you did, it just looked to me that you were proving that $\omega$ is root of $f$ at first sight.

Comment: @Ennar I figured as much, but I thought the elaboration would help other readers (at you was a courtesy).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use Euclidean division by $(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(x) = k(x)g(x)+r(x)$ where $r$ is linear. Then if $a,b$ are a roots of $g(x)$ we have $a^3=b^3=1$ and $a,b\ne 1$. Then

$$f(a)= a^{10}+a^5+1 = a+a^2+1 =0$$ so $r(a)=0$. The same is true for $b$, so $r(b)=0$.
Thus $r$ has two different zeroes and so $r\equiv 0$ and thus $g\mid f$.

Comment: Easier to do it for a *generic* root $x,\,$ e.g. see my answer.