# Find a prime that divides $14^7+14^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

As the title says we seek to

> Find a prime that divides $14^7+14^2+1$

There is a caveat though. This was part of a contest for high-school students so undergraduate Number Theory tools such as modular arithmetic should be avoided if we wish to remain true to the spirit of the competition.

That said, I did verify-employing exactly such tools-that if $p$ is the said prime then $p\neq2,3,5,7$.

Probably some form of simplifying the expression is required to solve it but it eludes me.

***EDIT***

The initial formulation of this question was "find the smallest such prime". This is highly unlikely to be achieved by pen and paper on the timeframe of a contest. For more details on why one can look at @lulu's answer below.

As noted on the comments by @JyrkiLahtonen, a similar question was posted before.

***See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/237785) as well for answers.***

Comment: It does factor, but that doesn't tell me why one of the sides is the smallest prime: $(x^7+x^2+1)=(x^2+x+1)(x^5-x^4+x^2-x+1)$

Comment: @lulu 3-digits Great..I thought about trial and error but that is discouraging. I will have the proposed solution available in a few hours but I am sure that it does not involve modular.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2012344/11619). That is closed for missing context, so I won't vote to close this as duplicate. It actually isn't because no attention to the smallest prime factor was given there. +1 to all

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I will edit again to link to your answer. Since it is a common  cyclotomic polynomial (not common for me unfortunately) it might well be of interest again and in order to avoid future duplicates..

Comment: Please link to Bill Dubuque's (=Number's) answer instead. It is more general.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Done, thanks again!

Comment: This was last year's exercise 4 from a Greek contest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prime factor of $A=14^7+14^2+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012344/prime-factor-of-a-1471421)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can factor the polynomial $$x^7+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)\times (x^5-x^4+x^2-x+1)$$

Letting $x=14$ shows that $211$ is a prime factor.  You still have to prove it is the least prime factor, but at least you can work with a smaller number.

Comment: ...how do you know one of the sides is the smallest prime for $x=14$?

Comment: Ok, this simplifies things. +1

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake How long did competitors have to solve the problem?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt   Because it is easy to check that $211$ is prime.  You still have to prove that the other factor, $499591$, is not divisible by any prime $<211$ but at least this is a simpler computation.

Comment: @lulu the computation still seems infeasible for a high school math contest

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt There were $4$ questions-if I am not mistaken this was the last one (most difficult?) and participants had $3$ hours to finish.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt  It's pencil and paper. I grant you it is a bit ugly.  Personally, I declined to check the other factor (up to $211$) by hand.  Wouldn't take more than $15$ minutes though.  Anyway, this is the best idea for it I have!

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Oh wow, in that case, you could indeed make this method work.

Comment: Ok fellows, I messed up-the exact wording of the test-I did not have a chance to see it myself yet-was "find a prime number" ,not the smallest. I will obviously accept this answer and Edit the question. Sorry

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake  Oh, that's much easier.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Nice, though I wonder how does one arrive at this factorization with pencil and paper :)

Comment: @lulu I just found out myself-a friend's pupil took part on this so I did not have a first-hand account. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: How did you factor that polynomial?

Comment: @Ovi  It's essentially cyclotomic.  Obviously a primitive cube root of $1$ is a root so it is clear that $x^2+x+1$ is a factor.  Actually, that remark is sufficient to solve the problem, but once you have one factor it is easy to find another.  This sort of factoring comes up all the time in high school math challenge problems.

Answer (score 3):

The reason we can get one factor immediately is that $7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$ As a result, both nontrivial roots of unity are roots of $x^7 + x^2 + 1,$ meaning that $(x - \omega)(x- \omega^2) = x^2 + x + 1$ must divide the polynomial $x^7 + x^2 + 1.$ Here $\omega^3 = 1$ but $\omega \neq 1$

If this seems uncomfortable, just consider that $x^2 + x + 1$ is the minimal polynomial for $\omega$ over $\mathbb Q,$ and must divide any polynomial for which $\omega$ is a root. Furthermore, the Gauss theorem on content tells us that the quotient polynomial has integer coefficients, not just rational.

Similar: the polynomial $x^{141} + x^{93} + x^{82} + x^{44} + 1$ is divisible by $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1,$ consider a fifth root of unity.

Comment: Nice observation +1!

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake  I added a quintic problem similar to the cubic. You could ask your friend to find a ***squared prime*** that divides $$ 3^{141} + 3^{93} + 3^{82} + 3^{44} + 1 $$ Oh, I see, contest rather than friend.

Comment: @I will! (When he sees it I am not sure he will remain a friend for much longer though..)

Answer (score 1):

$$x^7+x^2+1=x^7-x+x^2+x+1=x(x^3-1)(x^3+1)+x^2+x+1=$$
$$=(x^2-x)(x^2+x+1)(x^3+1)+x^2+x+1=$$
$$=(x^2+x+1)(x^5-x^4+x^2-x+1).$$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?