# Divisibility of polynomials in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields

Is the following known (or even correct)?

Let $q = p^n$ be a prime power.

Let $f(x), g(x) \in F_q[x]$ with $f(x) = x^m + ax^r + b$ with $a,b \ne 0$ and 
$g(x) = x^{mt} + cx^{rt} + d$ with $c,d \ne 0$ such that $f|g$

Then $t = p^i$ for some $i \ge 0$ and $c = a^{t}, d = b^{t}$.

ie. if the ${\bf exponents}$ match up nicely, then divisibility implies that $g$ is a Frobenius style power or $f$.

Note that $f$ and $g$ being trinomials is not the important part, but
only that they have the same number of terms and the corresponding exponents divide as indicated.

Note that if $t = p^i$ then $f^{t} = x^{mt} + a^{t}x^{rt} + b^{t}$ holds.
I'm looking for the converse or something close to it.

Comment: $x^2-1$ divides $x^4-1$, but $(-1)\ne(-1)^2$.

Comment: OK.  I've fixed up the question a bit to get away from this solution. How about just trinomials dividing trinomials to start?

Comment: $x^2-2x+1$ divides $x^4-2x^2+1$. $x^2-4x+4$ divides $x^4-8x^2+16$.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The following mechanism producing counterexamples springs to mind.

Consider for example the irreducible polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ from $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$. Its zeros, say $\alpha$ and conjugates, are third roots of unity, and therefore satisfy the equation $\alpha^7=\alpha$. Implying that they are also zeros of $f(x^7)$. Implying that
$$f(x)\mid f(x^7)=x^{14}+x^7+1.$$

Actually this divisibility relation holds in all characteristics (even zero). For exactly [the same reason](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/11619).

---

More generally, this happens to ALL irreducible trinomials over ANY finite field. The zeros of any irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ are roots of unity of some order, say $\ell$, and consequently $f(x)\mid f(x^{1+k\ell})$ for all $k$. The polynomial $f(x^{1+k\ell})$ is obviously a trinomial with the exponents matched up as prescribed. All you need to do is to select $k$ such that $1+k\ell$ is not a power of the characteristic.

Comment: And the trinomial need not even be irreducible. As long as its constant term is non-zero, all its zeros are roots of unity of some order. We can use the least common multiple of those orders in the role of $\ell$ above.

Comment: Thanks.  What if we force $t=p^i$?  Do the coefficients then have to lign up as $c = a^{p^i}$ and $d = b^{p^i}$?

Comment: Did you not see my examples in the comments, Dan?

Comment: Are you still here, Dan?