# Prove $3^x+9^x+1$ is divisible by 13 if $x=3n+1$

Tags: number-theory

I don't know how to start thinking about this problem, I was going to try to prove it by induction, but I think I'm on the wrong path. Any hints?

Comment: The order of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(13\mathbb{Z})^*$ is $3$ since $3^3=27\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. It follows that the remainder of $1+3^x+9^x\pmod{13}$ only depends on $x\pmod{3}$ and you just have to test $x\in\{0,1,2\}$ to get that $1+3^x+9^x\equiv 0\pmod{13}$ **iff** $x\not\equiv 0\pmod{3}$.

Comment: "It follows that the remainder only depends on x" could you explain this a little more? I understand that 3 has order 3 in that ring, but I don't get how to use that fact.

Comment: $3^{x+3k}\equiv 3^{x}\pmod{13}$, hence $3^{x}\pmod{13}$ is the same thing as $3^{x\pmod{3}}\pmod{13}$.

Comment: Oh, of course, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $3^{3n}\equiv 1 \bmod 13$, and that $9^{3n}\equiv 1 \bmod 13$.

Edit: Typo!

Comment: Oh, so $3^(3n+1)≡3 mod13$ and  $9^(3n+1)≡9 mod13$, so the sum is $3+9+1=0 mod13$?

Comment: @Lowkey Bingo! Anytime you work with modular arithmetic, the key is usually going to be in exploiting some kind of cyclic pattern. This even applies to iterated modular exponentiation.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Below put $\,x = 3,\,\ \{A,B,C\} = \{2n,n,0\}\ $  for any $\,n\not\equiv 0\pmod{\!3}$

**Lemma** $\ x^{2}\!+\!x\!+\!1\mid x^A\! +\! x^B\! +\! x^C\ $ if $ \ \{A,B,C\}\equiv \{2,1,0\}\pmod{\!3}.\ $

**Proof** $ $ Special case of a simple proof in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/242).

Comment: Many further examples are in [this list.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2012344?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you! I was actually confused by the other comment, and this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposition** $$y^{2n}+y^n+1$$ is divisible by $y^2+y+1$ if integer $n$ is not divisible by $3$

If $y^2+y+1=0,y=w,w^2$ where $w$ is a complex cube root of unity

Consider $n=3m+1,3m+2$

Comment: I am very confused by what you are trying to say with your answer... that we should prove the stronger statement? That there is a cube root of unity involved in what we are looking at?

Comment: @RandomMathGuy, Yes we have derived a generalization. Set $y=3$

Comment: @lab_bhattacharjee Except you didn't actually derive it. You just stated the proposition, and then the definition of a cube root of unity.

Comment: @RandomMathGuy, follow the last line: for $n=3m+1$ $$w^{2(3m+1)}+w^{3m+1}+1=0$$

Comment: @lab_bhattacharjee And that is still not a complete proof of your proposition. How do you intend to generalize that away from cube roots of unity to modular arithmetic?

Comment: I find it very unfortunate you seem to be unwilling to share this line of reasoning with the community, so I will; it is really clever to recognize that $3$ and $9$ play the role of cube roots of unity $\bmod 13$, and that because of this so long as their exponents don't cause them to degenerate we will have that the sum of all three roots will be congruent to $0$, giving us the divisibility property that we want.

Comment: @RandomMathGuy It's a special case of the result I cite in my answer. For many examples see [this linked questions list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2012344?lq=1)

Comment: @BillDubuque I had actually never seen this before, and I love it! Thanks for posting your answer and a link to that post.

Comment: @RandomMathGuy Yes, it isn't as well know as it should be. But it is quite natural  (and obvious) once one masters modular arithmetic.