# Why do all primes $n>3$ satisfy $\,309\mid 20^n-13^n-7^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the following... $309|(20^n-13^n-7^n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.
I invested lotof time to it and finally went to WolframAlpha for help by typing... 
Solve $309k=20^n-13^n-7^n$ over the integers. It returned the following...[image] [image] Note that all the primes are generated here. Can someone please explain why? Thanks! EDIT: the formulas suggested in the answerare too complicated, but this is so simple!

Comment: Is it false that it generates all the primes?

Comment: It is easy to picture why there might be a solution for all prime $n$.  However, the interesting part of the pattern is that $n=5\cdot 5$ and $n=5\cdot 7$ both appear, yet neither $n=3\cdot 3$ nor  $n=5\cdot 5$ appear.  Which odd composites admit solutions?

Comment: There are no even numbers ..

Comment: It seems like $n \equiv \pm1 \pmod 6$.

Comment: Yeah right but why do only specific composites arrive?

Comment: All the primes(except 2 and 3) are of the form $6k\pm 1$ if you generate all such numbers then you're bound to also generate all prime numbers. Not sure if the above generates all the numbers of the form $6k\pm1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$20^6 \equiv 13^6 \equiv 7^6 \equiv 229 \bmod 309$, so $20^n \equiv 13^n + 7^n \mod 309$ if and only if $20^{n+6} \equiv 13^{n+6} + 7^{n+6} \bmod 309$.  Since it does work for $n=1$ and $n=5$, but not for $0$, $2$, $3$ or $4$, we find that $20^n \equiv 13^n + 7^n \bmod 309$ if and only if $n \equiv 1$ or $5 \bmod 6$.

All primes except $2$ and $3$ are congruent to $1$ or $5 \bmod 6$.  $2$ or $3$ can't divide a number congruent to $1$ or $5 \bmod 6$, so it's not easy for a small number of this form to be composite. The first few composites are $25 = 5^2$, $35 = 5 \cdot 7$, $49 = 7 \cdot 7$, $55 = 5 \cdot 11$, ...

Comment: +1 really cool.

Comment: @ShamimAkhtar If you had entered your sequence $\,5,7,11,13,\ldots, 65$  into OEIS you'd obtain a unique match: [A007310](https://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C7%2C11%2C13%2C17%2C19%2C23%2C25%2C29%2C31%2C35%2C37%2C41%2C43%2C47%2C49%2C53%2C55%2C59%2C61%2C65&sort=&language=english&go=Search) = Numbers congruent to $1$ or $5$ mod $6$. Once you know that the rest is easy. That's the first method one should try on problems like this (when the pattern is not already clear from prior knowledge).

Comment: At https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328782/proving-largest-power-of-a2-abb2-that-divides-ap-bp-a-bp-for-odd-p there is a proof that in general $(a^2-ab+b^2)$ divides $a^{6k+r} -b^{6k+r} -(a-b)^{6k+r}$ for $r = 1, 5$.  The question at hand is a particular case with $a=20, b=13$ where $(a^2-ab+b^2)=309$

Comment: @Mark We can also proceed analogously as I do [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/242) (iirc this specific case is done in some other question here).

Answer (score 1):

So far you have only shown evidence that *some* of the primes are generated here, not all of them.  It's interesting how many there are, though.  There are some polynomials that generate an exorbitant number of primes. [Here are some examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Prime_formulas_and_polynomial_functions).  You will likely have to do a lot more work than just exploring the idea numerically to prove that all primes are generated.  Even if you do, these functions aren't super interesting because they produce non-primes as well.  You won't know whether a number that is generated is prime or not until you test it for primality, so it's not like it can be used to generate the $n^{th}$ prime without having to do lots more computation.  Quite cool, though.

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Comment: I tapped the show more but wolframalpha doesnt show more

Comment: I'm afraid I canot

Comment: Is this a standard question in mse? I too am afraid if any moderator marks this as off topic

Comment: It's a perfectly acceptable question, although it's probably much more difficult to answer than we think.  As a result, you're probably either not going to get an answer or get a very strange one.  I could be wrong, number theory isn't my thing.

Comment: Just ok... i liked this thing greatly

Answer (score 1):

A trivial observation is that it does not generate all the odd primes:  $3$ is missing.

However, I can verify that all primes up to $59359$ (other than $2$ and $3$) are represented.

This has a lot do to with the fact that $(a^2-ab+^2)$ is a apparently factor of $a^n-b^n-(a-b)^n$ for all prime $n>3$.  Here, $a=20, b=13$.

But that fact is at least as interesting as your observation, and I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: How can you verify?

Comment: Mathematica is very fast in determining residues mod 309.