# How to approach this divisibility problem on polynomial

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Prove that the polynomial $x^{9999} + x^{8888} + x^{7777} + ... + x^{1111} + 1$ is divisible by $x^9 + x^8 + x^7 + ... + x + 1$.

I have no idea how to approach this problem, some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=x^{9999}+x^{8888}+x^{7777}+\cdots+x^{1111}+1$ and $g(x)=x^9+x^8+x^7+\cdots+x+1$.

If $g(\alpha)=0$, then $\alpha^{10}=(\alpha-1)g(\alpha)+1=1$.

So, $f(\alpha)=\alpha^{9999}+\alpha^{8888}+\alpha^{7777}+\cdots+\alpha^{1111}+1=\alpha^9+\alpha^8+\alpha^7+\cdots+\alpha+1=0$.

$f(x)$ is divisible by $x-\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ such that $g(\alpha)=0$.

If $\alpha$ is a repeated root of $g(x)=0$, then $g(\alpha)=g'(\alpha)=0$.

Since $g(x)(x-1)=x^{10}-1$, $g'(\alpha)(\alpha-1)+g(\alpha)=10\alpha^{9}$ and hence $\alpha=0$.

However, $g(0)\ne0$.

$g(x)$ has no repeated root.

$f(x)$ is divisible by $g(x)$.

Comment: @Macavity You are right. We need to prove that the roots of $g(x)$ are single roots.

Comment: I don't understand this argument: If $g(\alpha)=0$, then $\alpha^{10}=(\alpha-1)g(\alpha)+1=1$

Comment: Aries used the fact that $\alpha^{10} - 1$ factors into $(\alpha - 1)(\alpha^9 + \alpha^8 + \cdots + 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Call it $\, f \div g.\ $ Note $\,\color{#c00}{x^{\large 10}\equiv 1}\pmod{\!g}\,$ by $\,x^{\large 10}\!-1 = (x\!-\!1)g,\,$ so

$\!\bmod g\!:\ x^{\large r+10q}\equiv x^{\large r}(\color{#c00}{x^{\large 10}})^{\large q}\equiv x^{\large r}\,\Rightarrow\, f\equiv g\equiv 0,\ $ so $\ g\mid f$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/242) for more examples and generalizations.

Comment: Which theorem is this called? $\,\color{#c00}{x^{\large 10}\equiv 1}\pmod{\!g}\,$

Comment: @Simba That's the *definition* of congruence: $\, f'\equiv f\pmod{\!g}\,$ means $\,f' = f + gh\,$ for some polynomial $h,\,$ i.e $\ g\mid f'-f,\,$ i.e. $\,g\,$ divides $\,f'-f.\,$ The [congruence sum & product rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) hold for polynomials just like for integers (same proofs work).

Comment: Very nice and generalisable  approach.. +1

Answer (score 0):

$$ ( x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1) \left(x^{9990} - x^{9989} \right) =  x^{9999} - x^{9989}$$

So,

$$ x^{9999} - x^{9979} = x^{9999} - x^{9989} + x^{9989} - x^{9979} =  ( x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1) \left(x^{9990} - x^{9989} + x^{9980} - x^{9979} \right) $$

Continuing in this way, we see that:

$$ x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1\ \vert\ x^{9999} - x^9, $$

$$ x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1\ \vert\ x^{8888} - x^8, $$

$$ \ldots$$

$$ x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1\ \vert\ x^{1111} - x^1, $$

$$ x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1\ \vert\ 1 - 1, $$

Therefore,

$$ x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1\ \vert\ x^{9999} - x^9 + x^{8888} - x^8 + \ldots + x^{1111} - x^1 + 1 - 1,\quad \text{ i.e.,} $$

$$ x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1\ \vert\ x^{9999} + x^{8888} + \ldots + x^{1111} + 1 - \left( x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1 \right) $$

$$ \implies x^9 + x^8 + \ldots + x + 1\ \vert\ x^{9999} + x^{8888} + \ldots + x^{1111} + 1.$$

Comment: Wait, is this wrong? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

$$
x^{9999}+x^{8888}+x^{7777}+...+x^{1111}+1
=\frac{x^{11110}-1}{x^{1111}-1}
=\frac{(x^{10})^{1111}-1}{x^{1111}-1}
=\frac{(x^{10}-1)p(x)}{x^{1111}-1}=\frac{(x^9+x^8+x^7+...+x+1)p(x)}{q(x)}
$$
So it is enough to show that $\gcd(x^{10}-1,x^{1111}-1)=x-1$. Let $w_k=e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{10}}$, $0\leq k\leq 9$. Then $w_k^{1111}-1=w_k-1=0$ iff $k=0$. So $x-w_k$ divides $x^{1111}-1$ iff $w_k=1$.

What's wrong here? You downvote!

Comment: If there is a wrong math please tell me I delete my answer.

Comment: Someone downvoted me too yesterday. I think someone is spamming downvotes...

Comment: Under every stone you can find an enemy...