# How to think of factorising $x^7+x^2+1$ to $(x^2+x+1)(x(x-1)(x^3+1)+1)$ (Thales 2016)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, intuition, factoring

I was just doing the following question:

Find a prime number which divides the number $A=14^7+14^2+1$.

I solved it by finding the result which is $A=105413504+196+1=105413701$ and then trying out all prime numbers till I found that 211 divides it. However, obviously this is extremely tedious. I hence looked at the solution which says that $x^7+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x(x-1)(x^3+1)+1)$ and from here by saying that $x=14$ we get the solution. However I can't seem to think of how to intuitively turn  $x^7+x^2+1$ into $(x^2+x+1)(x(x-1)(x^3+1)+1)$. I realize that from the question it is obvious to go looking for factors of A and hence trying to factorize $14^7+14^2+1$, but I can't work out how to go about factorizing it, what are the steps which you need to take in order to factorize a given polynomial. Could you please explain to me how to go about factorizing such an expression and how to intuitively think of each step?

Comment: Μιχάλη δε νομίζω πως υπάρχει στάνταρ τρόπος για να παραγοντοποιείς ένα πολυώνυμο. Εφόσον σκέφτηκες ότι πρέπει να παραγοντοποιήσεις το $f(x)=x^7+x^2+1$ τότε μάλλον θα πρέπει να κάνεις κάποιες δοκιμές μέχρι να δεις ότι κάτι δουλεύει. πχ εδώ θα έπρεπε να δεις ότι πρέπει να προσθαφαιρέσεις το $x$ (το οποίο ίσως δεν είναι και τόσο δύσκολο να το φανταστείς).

Comment: Αν θες δες αν μπορείς να παραγοντοποιήσεις το $x^{10}+x^5+1$ και το $x^8+x^4+1$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prime factor of $A=14^7+14^2+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012344/prime-factor-of-a-1471421)

Comment: Since that question is closed, I propose that we merge the two questions.

Comment: @TobyMak Merging is usually never a good idea.

Comment: @Michael Since you ask about intuition, see especially the link I gave in my answer in the proposed dupe to the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque   I think in the topic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012344 we have no context and attempts. Is this topic should be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:
$$x^7+x^2+1=x^7-x^4+x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^4(x-1)+x^2-x+1)=$$
$$=(x^2+x+1)(x^5-x^4+x^2-x+1).$$

Comment: Hello Mr. Rozenberg, thank you for responding, however I have one quick question, how did you think of adding $x^4-x^4$ to the polynomial?

Comment: @Michael  I just saw that $x^4+x^2+1=x^4+2x^2+1-x^2=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ and $x^7-x^4=x^4(x^3-1)$ gives a factor $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: Understood implicitely, thanks a lot Mr. Rozenberg

Comment: @Michael  You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can "see" that $\omega = \exp \left( \frac{2i\pi}{3}\right)$ and $\omega^2= \exp \left( \frac{-2i\pi}{3}\right)$ are roots of $x^7+x^2+1$, therefore $x^7+x^2+1$ factorizes by $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: I'd recommend calling it $\omega$ instead of $j$, as $j$ is a common symbol for $i$.

Comment: hello thanks for your response but what is exp()

Comment: @J.G. French notations, my bad :) I edited.

Comment: @Michael $\exp$ is the exponential... Do you know what are the complex roots of $x^2+x+1$ ?

Comment: no, I have heard of complex numbers and know how to use them...sort of:). But apart from that no

Comment: +1 nice elegance

Comment: @Michael Don't worry, you'll get to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) if you study complex numbers just a little more.

Comment: @Michael Ok, then in a few time studying complex numbers, you will be able to get the roots of any quadratic polynomial. In particular, the two complex roots of $x^2+x+1$ are very useful, and with a little bit of practise, you will see directly that they are also roots of $x^7+x^2+1$... which explains why it factorizes by $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: ok thanks a lot @TheSilverDoe

Answer (score 1):

By the factor theorem, $x^7+x^2+1$ has no rational roots and no linear factors over $\Bbb Z$, so we look for quadratic factors. To avoid non-integer coefficients, the only such factors are of the form $x^2+ax+1$. The case $a=1$ looks especially promising because, modulo $x^2+x+1$,$$x^3+1\implies x^7=x\implies x^7+x^2+1=0.$$This is essentially the reasoning in @TheSilverDoe's answer, but saves us having to work with explicit roots. As for finding the quotient, note$$\begin{align}x^7+x^2+1&=x(x^6-1)+x^2+x+1\\&=x(x^3-1)(x^3+1)+x^2+x+1\\&=(x^2+x+1)(x(x^3-1)(x+1)+1).\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** $x^2+x+1$ always divides $x^a+x^b+x^c$ if $\{a, b, c) \equiv \{0, 1, 2\} \mod 3$.  Hence it is easy to note $14^7+14^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {14^2+14+1}$, and all that remains is checking primality of $211$.

In case you wish to find the other factor(s), in this case, it may be simpler to consider dividing by $x^3-1$, like so:
$$x^7+x^2+1 = x^4(x^3-1) + x(x^3-1)+(x^2+x+1)$$
$$\implies \frac{x^7+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1} = x^4(x-1)+x(x-1)+1=(x-1)(x^4+x)+1$$

Comment: Please don't repost (other user's) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/242) from prior duplicates.

Comment: @BillDubuque I see the resemblance in notation in the first line now that you point out. However yours isn't the first time i have seen that principle, in fact there is a more general version i have mentioned somewhere else in comments in  past posts, nor have i posted this one after seeing yours.  i hope you agree rest of my answer doesn't have to be from any of your posts either.