# find all integers m such that the number $m^5+m+1$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring

I really don't know how to start this problem. The problem should be related to factoring the equation to derive an answer, but I don't know how.

Comment: $m^5+m+1=(m^2+m+1)(m^3-m^2+1).$ And for your case one of these factors must be $ 1,$  which won't be difficult to solve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Bumblebee or $-1.$

Comment: Same methods in the linked dupe work, see esp. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/242).