# prove that a number N is divisible by $5^k$ if the last k digits are divisible by $5^k$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

prove that a number $N$ is divisible by $5^k$ if the last $k$ digits are divisible by $5^k$.

Comment: **Hint** $\ \ \large 5^K\mid 10^K\, \Rightarrow\,\ N\bmod 5^K =\, \overbrace{(N\bmod 10^K)}^{\large {\rm last}\ K\ {\rm digits}} \bmod 5^K\   \begin{align}  \\ \\ \end{align}  $

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242) for more examples of this method of **dividing first by a simpler multiple** (here $10^K$ is *simpler* to divide (or mod) by since we are using radix $10 =$ decimal arithmetic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Another presentation*:

By Euclidean division, we can write any number $N$ as 
$$N=N_1 10^k+N_2,\quad 0\le N_2<10^k.$$
Observe the remainder is just the number represented by the last $k$ digits of $N$, and it is clear from this equality that $N$ is divisible by $5^k$ if and only if $N_2$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the number obtained by taking the last $k$ digits of $N$, and let $b = N-a$. Then $b$ has zeroes as its last $k$ digits and so is divisible by $10^k$ and therefore divisible by $5^k$. So we have $b \equiv 0 \pmod {5^k}$ which implies$N \equiv a \pmod {5^k}$, and so $N$ is divisible by $5^k$ iff the last $k$ digits are.

Answer (score 0):

If the number formed by the last $ k$ digits  on $N$ is denoted by $M$ then $$ N=M+(N-M)$$

Note that both $M$ and $(N-M)$ are divisible by $5^k$ because $(N-M)$ ends with $k$ zeros.