# $\omega$ is a solution of $x^2+x+1=0$, find $\omega^{10}+\omega^5+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, quadratics

I am working on a scholarship exam practice assuming high school or pre-university math knowledge. I am stuck at the question below:

> Let $\omega$ be a solution of the equation $x^2+x+1=0$. Then $\omega^{10}+\omega^5+3=.....$

My first question is how it would be possible since the discriminant of $x^2+x+1=0$ is less than $0$ so I am not sure how I can continue or start from here. The answer key provided is $2$. Please advise.

Comment: The equation doesn't have any real root, but it does have complex roots.

Comment: Minor variant of [Polynomial division: Is this trick obvious?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224765/polynomial-division-is-this-trick-obvious) (See [Bill Dubuque's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266201/omega-is-a-solution-of-x2x1-0-find-omega10-omega53/3266207#comment6717690_3266220) for why it should be closed)

Comment: I don't agree, it shouldn't  closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\omega$ is such that $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ i.e. $\omega^2=-\omega-1$

Therefore $\omega^3=\omega \cdot \omega^2=\omega(-\omega-1)=-\omega^2-\omega=1$

$\omega^5=\omega^3 \cdot \omega^2=\omega^2=-\omega-1$

$\omega^{10}=(\omega^5)^2=(-\omega-1)^2=\omega^2+1+2\omega=\omega$

Hence $\omega^{10}+\omega^5+3=\omega-\omega-1+3=2$

Answer (score 13):

Dividing the polynomial $x^{10}+x^5+3$ by $x^2+x+1$ leaves a remainder of $2$. Plugging in $x=\omega$ yields your answer is $2$.

Comment: +1 That's an extremely good approach for people not well versed with complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, I would go farther and say that the point of this problem is not to test one's understanding of complex numbers, but rather to test if one understands the relationship between roots of a polynomial and polynomial division.

Comment: @pre-kidney is there a trick to see easily that the remainder is $2$? Or how would you recommend yo use division in this case?

Comment: Yes, there is a trick @Zacky which Bill Dubuque wrote up extremely well here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224765/polynomial-division-is-this-trick-obvious/3224776#3224776

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

As $\omega$ is a solution of $x^2+x+1=0,$

$$\omega^2+\omega+1=0$$

$$\omega^3-1=(\omega-1)(\omega^2+\omega+1)=0$$

$$\omega^{10}=(\omega^3)^3\cdot\omega\text{ and }\omega^5=\omega^3\cdot\omega^2$$

$$\omega^2+\omega=?$$

Comment: How is $x^{10}=x$?

Comment: @TreyAnupong because $\omega^3 = 1$, then $\omega^{10} = \omega^9 \cdot \omega = \omega$

Comment: @dcolazin $\omega$ is not $x$. This answer is confusing to a beginner, it should be $\omega$s.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, Is it fine, now?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes.

Answer (score 2):

$\omega^3=(\omega-1)(\omega^2+\omega+1)+1=1$.

$\omega^5=\omega^3\omega^2=\omega^2\ne1$ (as otherwise $\omega=-1-\omega^2=-2$, which is impossible)

$\omega^{10}+\omega^5+3=\dfrac{\omega^{15}-1}{\omega^5-1}+2=\dfrac{1-1}{\omega^5-1}+2=2$.

Comment: You need to make sure that the denominator is not also $0$, otherwise this is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$\begin{align}\omega^2+\omega+1&=0\\
\omega ^2&=-\omega-1\\
\omega^{10}&=-(\omega +1)^5=-\omega^5-5\omega^4-10\omega^3-10\omega^2-5\omega-1\\
\omega^{10}+\omega^5+3&=-5\omega^2(\omega^2+\omega+1)-5\omega(\omega^2+\omega+1)-1+3=2. \end{align}$$

Answer (score -2):

Since $$\omega^3-1=(\omega-1)(\omega^2+\omega+1)=0,$$ we obtain:
$$\omega^{10}+\omega^5+3=\omega^{10}-\omega+\omega^5-\omega^2+\omega^2+\omega+3=$$
$$=\omega(\omega^9-1)+\omega^2(\omega^3-1)+(\omega^2+\omega+1)+2=2.$$

Comment: This doesn't bring anything more to the existing answers and is unreadable to a beginner.

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier I added something. See now.

Comment: This was mentioned in CRUDE. Why did you gold-badge reopen? Do you not understand how it is a special case of [this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242).  We already have hundreds of (dupe) answers that show how to do these things. Why do you think we need more?

Comment: I think the starting problem is not duplicate.

Comment: Please see this [8-year-old meta post on **abstract** duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242). As someone who strives to bring order to motley inequalities, I would hope that you would be sympathetic to your peers who similarly strive to organize knowledge in other fields.