# Division in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: ring-theory, divisibility, euclidean-domain

I am studying the ring theory and I got some point like $(2+3i)$ divides $(-1+5i)$ in the Eucledian domain $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
I do not know that how it can be possible. Please let me know about this.

Comment: Here we can reduce divisiion by complex integers to division by integers by **rationalizing the denominator** of the quotient. This is a special of the general [method of simpler multiples.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do the division in $\mathbb{C}$:
$$
\frac{-1+5i}{2+3i}=\frac{(-1+5i)(2-3i)}{4+9}=\frac{-2+10i+3i-15i^2}{13}=1+i
$$
The quotient is in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

By the way, both $1+i$ and $2+3i$ are primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.