# Show that 9453(6824)$\equiv$6782(5675341)$\equiv$2 (mod 5)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Show that 9453(6824)$\equiv$6782(5675341)$\equiv$2 (mod 5)

I am very new to modular arithmetic and I am not entirely sure what this question is asking me to do, or how you would go about showing what it is looking for. I apologise if this is very simple, but I am looking for some clarification on what this actually means. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that $a \equiv b$ (mod $p$) and $c \equiv d$ (mod $p$) implies $ac \equiv bd$ (mod $p$)?

Comment: Yeah, I think I have seen this before, but how do you apply it to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $a\equiv r$ (mod $p$), where $r$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $p$.

What are the remainders when $9453, 6824, 6782$ and $5675341$ are divided by $5$?

Comment: So the remainders are 3, 4, 2 and 1

Comment: So can I say that 9453$\equiv$3 (mod 5) and 6824$\equiv$4 (mod 5) and 6782 $\equiv$2 (mod 5) and 5675341 $\equiv$1 (mod 5)? And using the rule above, then 3(4)$\equiv$2(1) (mod 5) so 12$\equiv$2 (mod 5)?

Comment: @Jamminermit that is perfectly correct.

Comment: which is the same as saying $12-2$ is divisible by 5.

Comment: @Jamminermit Another way is to compute the decimal units digits then reduce that $\bmod 5,\,$  i.e. $\, n\bmod 5 = (n\bmod 10)\bmod 5,\,$ a special case of the [method of simpler multiples.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* It is relatively easy to reduce numbers in decimal form modulo $5.$ Just expand out and note that any positive power of $10$ vanishes modulo $5.$ Thus, the residues are just the residues of the units digits, which are easy to do. Can you now proceed?

Comment: The residue $\bmod 5\,$ is the units digits *reduced* $\bmod 5,\,$ i.e. $\, n\bmod 5 = (n\bmod 10)\bmod 5,\,$ see my comment in Jerry's answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks. This is what I should have said.