# How to show that $2+\sqrt{5}i\not | 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gaussian-integers

How can I prove that there is no $x\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $x\cdot (2+\sqrt{5}i)= 3$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x=a+ib\sqrt{5}$. You have
$$x.(2+\sqrt{5}i)=(a+ib\sqrt{5})(2+\sqrt{5}i)=(2a-5b)+i\sqrt{5}(a+2b)$$

This is equal to $3$ iff $a+2b=0$ and $2a-5b=3$. This is easy to see that there are no solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Easier - simply rationalize the denominator - see my comment on the other answer. Please strive to close dupes of FAQs, not add more dupe answers.

Comment: I am sorry, @BillDubuque, king of duplicates.

Comment: I cannot delete it because people already answered it, why you are so mad you all know that searching for duplicates on this site is impaired

Answer (score -1):

*Hint:* If $(a+b\sqrt{5}i)(2+\sqrt{5}i)=3$, then $a^2+5b^2=1$ and so $a=\pm1$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, but maybe they don't see how to finish (or maybe they don't like the question quality, or maybe they think experienced users shouldn't be answering dupes of trivial FAQs). To finish note that the hint $\Rightarrow\, 3\mid 2+\sqrt{-5},\,$ contradiction. This is clearer by **rationalizing the denominator** $\, v/w = (v\bar w)(w\bar w)\,$ yielding $$ 2\!+\!\sqrt{-5}\mid 3\ \ {\rm in}\ \ \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{3}{2\!+\!\sqrt{-5}}  = \dfrac{2\!-\!\sqrt{5}}3\in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\ \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$$

Comment: @BillDubuque Your argument is indeed quicker and maybe easier, but to apply it, you go *outside* from $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ (in $\mathbb{C}$, or at least in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$)... In my opinion, this is less elegant than proving directly the result. But it works well, though ! (and not my downvote either on lhf's answer)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe It's trivial to eliminate the use of *fractions:* rewrite is as $\,w\mid n\iff w\bar w\mid n\bar w.\,$ Then rat'ing the denom becomes rat'ing the divisor. More generally see the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242). $\ \ $