# How do we take (something) $(mod~(3, x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1))$ and what is a normative canonical representative of a polynomial?

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, quotient-spaces, canonical-transformation

I have two questions in the following explanation:

"Consider the quotient ring $S/3=Z_3[x]/(3,x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1)$. The canonical S/3-representative of $a\in Z[x]$ is the unique polynomial $b\in Z[x]$ of degree at most $n-2$ with coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$ such that;

$a\equiv b $ $(mod~(3, x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1))$. We write $\underline S3(a)$ for the canonical S/3 -representative of $a $.  We write $S3(a)$ when the choice of representative is not **normative**".

Question 1: How do we take modulo of : (something) $(mod~(3, x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1))$ ? Do we first take (something) mod 3, then take $(mod~( x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1))$ of it afterwards?

Question 2: What does **normative** mean in the context above?

Comment: The order in which you mod out by something doesn't matter, which can be proven with the Correspondence Theorem.

Comment: First time I’ve seen the word “normative” ! And I’m a geezer. My guess is that it’s saying that other people may choose different representatives, without risking disapproval from the author. In other words, I don’t think it’s a mathematical word at all.

Comment: @JetChung  yes you are right, the order of mod does not change anything but  my main question  here is how do we take the mod with two parameters? I never saw something like this. I mean I can take  just mod 3 or  just mod p(x) or mod 3 then mod p(x) but never seen  mod (3, p(x)) where p(x) is a polynomial?

Comment: @Esra Yes, if you consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of integer polynomials, then the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3, x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \ldots + 1)$ is formed by first setting $3 = 0$, then $x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \ldots + 1 = 0$ (or the other way around if you'd like).

Comment: Also, I believe the ring $S/3$ should be $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3, \ldots)$ and not $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(3, \ldots)$ as this is redundant.

Comment: With $\,g = (x^n-1)/(x-1),\,$ a normal form of $f$ is $\,f\bmod g,\,$ calculated $\bmod 3$, or more simply $\,(f\bmod x^n-1)\bmod g$ where we first reduce using the rewrite rule $\,x^n\equiv 1,\,$ then eliminate $\,x^{n-1}\,$ by $\,x^{n-1}\equiv x^{n-1}-g = -x^{n-2}-\cdots -x-1,\,$ see the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242).