# How to prove that $\overline{a_na_{n-1}...a_ka_{k-1}...a_0} ≡ \overline{a_{k-1}a_{k-2}...a_0}$ mod($5^k$)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

This is a problem from a school textbook that I currently learn math with, this is the chapter on divisibility properties from the **number theory**.

There is two theorems in the chapter:

1. $\overline{a_n a_{n-1} a_{n-2}...a_1 a_0} ≡ a_n + a_{n-1} + ... + a_1 + a_0$ (mod. 9) => (mod. 3) as well.
2. $\overline{a_n a_{n−1} a_{n−2} ... a_1 a_0} ≡ a_0 − a_1 + a_2 − a_3 + ... + ( −1 )^n a_n$ (mod 11).

I understood the proofs of both of the theorems and yet the theorems seem to be inapplicable to the equation below that needs to be proven. Neither can I apply anything learned before in the previous lessons on the number theory.

$\overline{a_na_{n-1}...a_ka_{k-1}...a_0} ≡ \overline{a_{k-1}a_{k-2}...a_0}$ mod($5^k$)

How to approach such problems, how to prove this one in particular ?

Comment: Have you tried the cases $k=1$ and $k=2$?

Comment: $\overline{a_na_{n-1}...a_ka_{k-1}...a_0} = 10^k q + r,\,$ for $q = \overline{a_na_{n-1}...a_k},\,$ $\,r = \overline{a_{k-1}...a_0}$ so the claim is that $\bmod \color{#c00}{5^k}\!:\ 10^k q + r\equiv r,\,$ true by $10^k = \color{#c00}{5^k} 2^k\equiv 0\,$ by linked [congruence laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Comment: **Or** we can view it as a reduction of a  divisibility test in radix (base) $b=10^k,\,$ i.e. an integer $n$ in radix $b$ is congruent to it "units" digits $\,= n\bmod b,\,$ so the congruence remains true mod any divisor of $b$, just like we can compute $\,n\bmod 5$ by first computing $\,n\bmod 10 = u = $ units digit in base $10$ then reducing $u$ modul0 $5,\,$ see the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque very nice of you. Close my question and give me links to "similar" questions, whereas there were no even radixes and polynomial congruences yet in the textbook that I learn math with 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two numbers differ by a number ending in $k$ zeroes. Such number is a multiple of $10^k=5^k2^k$, hence it is divisible by $5^k$. Hence they coincide $\textrm{mod }5^k$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).