# If $x^2 + x+ 1 = 0 $ find the value of $x^{1401} + x^{-1401}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the name of God
If $x^2 + x+ 1 = 0$ find the value of $x^{1401} + x^{-1401}$.

I tried to factorize $x^{1401} + x^{-1401}$ by replacing $x$ with $a$ and $x^{-1}$ with $b$.

To factorize $a^{1401} + b^{1401}$, we can write it like this:

$$\begin{aligned}
a^{1401} + b^{1401} 
&= (a^{467})^3 + (b^{467})^3\\
&= (a^{467} + b^{467})(a^{934} -a^{467}b^{467} + b^{934})\\
&=(a+b)(a^{466}-a^{465}b + a^{464}b^2 \\
&\quad-\cdots + b^{466})(a^{934} -a^{467}b^{467} + b^{934}) \\
&=(a+b)(a^{466}-a^{465}b + a^{464}b^2 -\cdots\\
&\quad+ b^{466})(a^2-ab+b^2)(a^{932} + a^{931}b \\
&\quad-a^{929}b^3 - \cdots + b^{932})\end{aligned}$$

But it doesn't really seem to help to solve the question.

I don't know much about more advanced math topics, but $x$ is certainly a complex number. How is it possible that $x^{1401} + x^{-1401}$ is a real one? Do 'i's get omitted?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What is $x^3$ ..?

Comment: When you said "$x$ is certainly a complex number" you probably meant "$x$ is not a real number". Keep in mind that the set of real numbers is a subset of the set of the complex numbers. $1$ is a complex number, for example. That's said, there's nothing odd about that number been real. $i+\tfrac{1}{i}$ is real despite $i$ been not real.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I meant $x$ is a number that has two parts, a real and an imaginary part.

Comment: As in the dupe, by the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242), $\,x^2+x+1=0\Rightarrow x^3 = 1\,$ so now we can reduce it using [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) to reduce the exponents on $\,x\,$ modulo $3\ \ $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

$$x(x^2+x+1) = x^3+x^2+x = 0 \require{cancel}\implies x^3+\cancelto{0}{(x^2+x+1)} = 1$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question. does $x^{1401} + x^{-1401} -2 $ have factor $x^2 + x+ 1$ ?

Comment: @madfdadfd Multiplying if by $x^{1401}$ we get a *polynoomial* $f(x)$ that is $\equiv 0\pmod{x^3-1}$ so $f(x)$ is divisibile by $x^3-1$ so also divisibile by its factor $x^2+x+1\ \ $

Answer (score 6):

$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$$
Therefore
$$x^{1401}+x^{-1401}=(x^3)^{467}+(x^3)^{-467}=2$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Thanks for your answer